# Siguiente numero sin digitos repetidos

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Estoy haciendo esta funcion en la cual se pasa un numero por parametro; si este tiene algun digito repetido entonces busca el siguiente numero mas cercano mayor que no tenga digitos iguales.

> Ej: `proximoNumero(2002)` -> `return 2013`
>
> Ej: `proximoNumero(1001)` -> `return 1023`
>
> Ej: `proximoNumero(899)`  -> `return 901`

```js
function proximoNumero(numero){
    numero = (numero+1).toString().split('')
    for(let i=0; i<numero.length-1; i++){
        for(let j=i+1; j<numero.length; j++){
            if(numero[i] === numero[j]){
                console.log(`${numero} se repite ${numero[i]}`);
                proximoNumero(Number(numero.join('')))
            }
        }   
    }
    return numero.join('')
}

console.log(proximoNumero(1001));
```

mi funcion esta haciendo algo similar pero no entiendo porque una vez se llama recursivamente con un numero sin caracteres repetidos me regresa el primer numero que le es pasado por parametro

Comment: Imagino que el ejemplo que pones de 2002 debería devolver 2013, ¿no?

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace si exacto

Comment: error mio en el ejemplo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Te falta un return al hacer la llamada recursiva que rompa (salga de) el doble bucle:

```js
function proximoSinRepetidos(numero){
    numero = (numero+1).toString().split('')
    for(let i=0; i<numero.length-1; i++){
        for(let j=i+1; j<numero.length; j++){
            if(numero[i] === numero[j]){
                console.log(`${numero} se repite ${numero[i]}`);
                //Aquí te faltaba "return" delante
                return proximoSinRepetidos(Number(numero.join('')));
            }
        }   
    }
    return numero.join('')
}

console.log(proximoSinRepetidos(1001));
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! @Pablo-Lozano :)

Answer (score 7):

La [respuesta de @Pablo-Lozano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/294773/16597) es la más acertada.

Me pareció que podría ser útil (*quizás para otros usuarios*) dar una solución sin utilizar recursión.
Para lograrlo podemos hacer lo siguiente:

- Convertimos el número a arreglo (`[...`${number}`] ===> array`)
- Controlamos que en arreglo **SI** existe duplicados (`array.some((val, idx, arr) => arr.lastIndexOf(val) != idx) ===> bool`)
- Mientras esto se cumpla, incrementamos el number (`while (bool) number++`)
- Cuando ya no se cumpla retornamos el número que **No** contiene repetidos (`return number`).

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function proximoSinRepetidos(number) {
  while ([...`${number}`].some((val, idx, arr) => arr.lastIndexOf(val) != idx)) number++;
  return number;
}

console.log(proximoSinRepetidos(1001));
```

#### Ejemplo usando `RegExp`:

```js
function proximoSinRepetidos(number) {
  while (/(.).*\1/.test(number)) number++;
  return number;
}

console.log(proximoSinRepetidos(1001));
```

Comment: Gracias @Marcos no sabia del uso del `some()`

Comment: me gusta esa regex, no es necesario un full match como la que hice. +1

Answer (score 5):

Una alternativa distinta sería checkear con una regex si hay números repetidos, si hay repetidos sumamos uno:

```js
const noRepedido = (num) => /\d*(\d)\d*\1\d*/.test(num) ? noRepedido(++num) : num;


console.log(noRepedido(2002));
console.log(noRepedido(1001));
console.log(noRepedido(899));
console.log(noRepedido(22313));
```

De esta manera siempre trabajamos con números, no hacemos ninguna conversión explícita.
Usando la regex de @Marcos, que es mejor porque no busca un full math, quedaría simplemente:

```js
const noRepedido = (num) => /(.).*\1/.test(num) ? noRepedido(++num) : num;

console.log(noRepedido(2002));
```

Comment: tengo que aprender mas de regex.. veo que se puede solucionar muchos problemas con ellas, gracias @Emeeus

Comment: Si empleas una regex sobre un número, ten por seguro que internamente hay una conversión a string... no se puede aplicar una regex sobre un número directamente. Has de asumir representación en base 10, por ejemplo

Comment: Bueno si, hay una conversión implícita.