# ¿Como sustituir en JavaScript caracteres nulos por nada?

Tags: javascript, caracteres

Tengo la siguiente cadena con muchos "espacios" (que no son espacios):

```
var cadena = "60                                                C"
```

Esos espacios en realidad no son espacios, son caracteres nulos, su valor en `ASCII` es el numero 0 (cero), no encuentro la forma de sustituir esos caracteres nulos por nada mediante la función `replace` de `JavaScript`.

¿Alguien me puede dar una orientación? Hacer esto no funciona ya que los espacios no son espacios, son caracteres nulos.

```
cadena.replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que buscas, si quieres eliminar el exceso de espacios de una cadena con javascript puedes usar `cadena.split(' ').filter(String).join(' ');`

Comment: En el texto comenté que No son espacios, son caracteres nulos que no es lo mismo.

Comment: @IvanCaballeroCano prueba la solución planteada funciona, nadamas para quitar todos los espacios, en el `join` yo lo pondría así: `join('')` para que también quite lo que hay entre el 60 y la letra C

Comment: Por eso no coloque la respuesta, ese punto no me quedó claro @the-breaker e igual por eso aclaré que así lo haría por que no termine de entender ese punto XD

Comment: @the-breaker, me han hecho dudar... yo entendí que había que sacar todos, es decir, el resultado era `60C`. Dice "_sustituir esos caracteres nulos por nada_"

Comment: @Marcos esperemos al OP para que aclare las dudas.

Comment: Tengan en cuenta que esos "espacios" no son espacios en realidad, son caracteres nulos y tienen un tratamiento y ascci diferente que los reales espacios

Answer (score 8):

Puedes usar una [expresión regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions), puntualmente `\s`

> `\s`: Coincide con un solo carácter de espacio en blanco, incluyendo espacio, tabulación, avance de formulario, avance de línea y otros espacios unicode.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var cadena = "60            C"
console.log(cadena.replace(/\s/g, ''));
```

Comment: Por favor todos hablan de "Espacios", tengan en cuenta que NO SON ESPACIOS, son caractres nulos, cualquier cosa que implique en la solución el uso de espacios no funciona

Comment: @IvanCaballeroCano, `\s` no representa solo "espacios", sino que representa un grupo variado de caracteres entre los cuales está el "espacio". Yo copie exactamente la cadena en la pregunta y funciona. ¿Has intentado aplicar mi solución y no funciono? Si es así, por favor, comparte con nosotros la cadena en cuestión.

Answer (score 4):

El caracter que retorna 0 en `charCodeAt()` es **\u0000** ([NULL](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm) en UTF-16 que es lo que retorna [charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)), entonces, este sería un ejemplo usando `\s`:

```js
var str = `60\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000               
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000         
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000         
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000C`;

console.log("Longitud antes de regex: "+str.length);

str = str.replace(/\s/g,"");

console.log(str);

console.log("Longitud después de regex: "+str.length);
```

Como podemos ver, **quita los espacios pero no los nulos**, entonces podemos hacer esta expresión para quitar espacios y códigos nulos (código UTF-16 igual a 0): `/[\s\u0000]/g`

```js
var str = `60\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000               
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000         
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000         
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000C`;

console.log("Longitud antes de regex: "+str.length);

str = str.replace(/[\s\u0000]/g,"");

console.log(str);

console.log("Longitud despues de regex: "+str.length);
```

Pero esa expresión deja también otra cantidad de caracteres *invisibles* (de \x00 a x7F aproximadamente), por esa razón yo apuntaría hacia otro enfoque, que sería **elegir específicamente que deseas dejar pasar, en lugar de eliminar lo que no quieres**. Por ejemplo si quieres letras de a-z y números:

```js
var cadena = `60\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000               
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000         
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000         
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000C`

var cadenaLimpia = cadena.match(/[a-z\d]+/gi).join("");

console.log(cadenaLimpia);

console.log("Longitud después de regex: "+cadenaLimpia.length);
```

Comment: Creo que es bueno aclarar que modificaste tu respuesta en base a la mía, ya que fui el primero que investigo la raíz del problema e identifico la diferencia entre espacios y caracteres nulos, también la idea central de la respuesta es muy semejante. Considero que es importante dar crédito a otros usuarios si se dan respuestas basándose en sus aportes.

Comment: @the-breaker En realidad no, recién leo toda tu respuesta. Cuando vi el `.filter` ya no estaba muy de acuerdo porque personalmente prefiero las regex. Y la idea tampoco es la misma, mi idea es la misma que antes de la edición, es preferible elegir que dejar pasar antes que elegir que no dejar pasar.

Comment: @the-breaker si hubiera tomado parte de tu respuesta no tengo ningún problema en mencionarlo, como por ejemplo hice aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/294771/siguiente-numero-sin-digitos-repetidos/294797#294797 mencionando a Marcos.

Comment: de acuerdo, no hay problema, aunque me pareció muy sospechoso

Answer (score 2):

Como se indica los caracteres que se muestran en la cadena no son espacios sino caracteres nulos.

El carácter nulo tiene el [codigo ascii](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/) "0" y al imprimirse se muestra como un espacio, pero **no lo es**.

Por tanto dicho carácter es inmune a funciones que trabajan con espacios como:

```
cadena.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

Para deshacerse de dicho carácter se puede hacer un filtrado de los caracteres cuyo código ascii sea 0:

```
var ncad2 = cadena.split('').filter(c => c.charCodeAt()>0).join('');
```

Se emplea `charCodeAt()` para obtener el código ascii del carácter.

Todo lo explicado anteriormente se demuestra en el siguiente código:

```js
var noesespacio=String.fromCharCode(0);   //este es un caracter nulo

console.log(noesespacio);                 //al imprimirlo se muestra como un espacio  

var cadena =`60${noesespacio}C`;          //lo agregamos a una cadena

console.log(cadena);                      //dentro la cadena se ve como un espacio

var ncad = cadena.replace(/\s/g, '');     //empleamos replace

console.log(ncad);                        //vemos que no funciona

//filtrando el caracter por su codigo ascii
var ncad2 = cadena.split('').filter(c => c.charCodeAt()>0).join('');

console.log(ncad2);                       //vemos que funciona
```

y de ese modo se sustituyen los caracteres nulos por nada, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para reemplazar todas las ocurrencias de un caracter en una cadena usa una expresión regular y la bandera `g`

Ejemplo:

```js
var cadena = "60                                                C"
console.info(cadena.replace(/ /g,"")); // dentro de la expresión regular se incluye el tercer caracter de la cadena declarada previamente
```

---

Si quieres saber de que caracter se trata puedes usar `String.prototype.charCodeAt(index)`

Ejemplo

```js
var cadena = "60                                                C"
console.info(cadena.charCodeAt(2));
```

En este caso el primer caracter después de `60` tiene el código `32`.

Comment: Para copiar la cadena que publico el OP es necesario "editar" la pregunta y copiar la misma, de lo contrario lo que se copian son "espacios". En mi respuesta `charCodeAt(2) == 9`